# Can my boss make me come into work hours before my scheduled shift?

Tags: overtime, hours, retail

Lately I have been getting called to come into work earlier than my scheduled shift which I have agreed to on a day to day basis. Some days however I just simply cannot come in earlier than my scheduled shift since I have other plans. Can my employer demand that I come in before my scheduled shift on the same day I am supposed to go in?

Comment: Are you being paid for these hours?

Comment: Yes, I will be getting paid for the hours that I do come in early.

Comment: Where are you located? Local labor laws may apply here.

Comment: Your employer can demand whatever they want, unless it's illegal. You can, of course refuse. If your employer would prefer to have someone else than you, they can fire you. If you don't like their demands, you can quit. Anything else is going to be very country/state/contract specific.

Comment: For me personally, I couldn't have been fired when I didn't agree to come in during this time, but I would be treated less favourably. If I had done a lot of favours that week such as coming in early, I was more likely to get better hours on the rota next week, where as if I had classes or other responsibilities and could not, I got stuck with less shifts, or awkward hours. It's all about give or take which can be unfair

Answer (score 11):

In most cases you can't be obligated to come in when you aren't scheduled, but it helps your manager when you agree to. My guess is that if you are generally willing to help out when you can, and you explain to your boss when you can't (today I have an obligation), then your manager will most likely appreciate it and it probably won't affect you negatively.